# I am unevenly getting the socket time out exception

Tags: java, tomcat, alfresco

I am working on alfresco. which is hosted on tomcat.. my clients are connected to CIFS / Webdav .. but at certain period of time i am continuously getting the

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out error in the log..
```

can i decrease the time out period the server.xml file in tomcat

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Is it help full to resolve the error..

Regards,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Try this config:

```
<Connector port="8080" 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
redirectPort="8443" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxThreads="150" 
minSpareThreads="25" 
maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" 
acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
compression="on"
compressionMinSize="2048"
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"              
/>
```

You can turn of the compression if you think you don't need it. This is for Tomcat 6 and up.